# String split with comma and quotes in redshift using Regex

Tags: sql, regex, amazon-web-services, amazon-redshift

I have a string column in redshift table like:

```
String
["0","0","5","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"]
["0","0","0","8","30","0","0","0","0"]
["0","0"]
```

I want to split the string column to get the first 6 characters of the string in 6 different columns as shown below

| String | Col1 | Col2 | Col3 | Col4 | Col5 | Col6 |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| ["0","0","5","10","20","30","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0","0"] | 0 | 0 | 5 | 10 | 20 | 30 |
| ["0","0","0","8","30","0","0","0","0"] | 0 | 0 | 0 | 8 | 30 | 0 |
| ["0","0"] | 0 | 0 |  |  |  |  |

I am new to Redshift and regex concepts. Any help would be of great help.

Comment: [This](https://dwgeek.com/redshift-split-delimited-fields-into-table-records-and-examples.html/) may be helpfull for you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try [REGEXP_SUBSTR](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/REGEXP_SUBSTR.html):

```
select 
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(mystr, '[0-9]+', 1, 1) as col1,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(mystr, '[0-9]+', 1, 2) as col2,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(mystr, '[0-9]+', 1, 3) as col3,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(mystr, '[0-9]+', 1, 4) as col4,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(mystr, '[0-9]+', 1, 5) as col5,
  REGEXP_SUBSTR(mystr, '[0-9]+', 1, 6) as col6
from mytable;
```